# C# - Complex DELETE statement against an Access Database not affecting any rows

Tags: c#, ms-access

This seems really basic to me but it doesn't seem to want to work.

I'm trying to delete rows from an Access Database table based on records returned from a subquery. I'm not sure if it's a syntax issue or what might be wrong - I tried multiple versions. Whichever version I tried, the outcome was a syntax error or no rows were affected.

Here's my latest code that doesn't return an error:

```
        public bool DeletePlayerGamesRecords(int PlayerID, int NightID)
    {
        PinnacleConnection pcon = new PinnacleConnection();
        OleDbConnection conn = pcon.createConnection();
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
        string sql = "DELETE * FROM tblPlayerGames WHERE fk_player_id = @pID AND fk_game_id IN (SELECT tblGames.[ID] FROM tblGames WHERE fk_night_id = @nightID)";

        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            cmd.CommandText = sql;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pID", PlayerID);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nightID", NightID);
            cmd.Connection = conn;
            int affected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); //affected rows always 0!
            conn.Close();

            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            this.error = ex.Message;
            return false;
        }
    }
```

while debugging I determined that six rows should have been deleted, but none actually were.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think you'll need to provide more information about the table structure and possibly the data of the rows that you're trying to delete + parameter values.

Comment: I'm not well versed in access syntax, so I looked here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb177896%28v=office.12%29.aspx   it's not throwing an error, but isn't deleting records either

Comment: have you set break points in your code..? to see if it's hitting the catch portion of your code..?

Comment: indeed, I did... and it is going through each line without throwing an error.

Comment: try executing the query in Access directly and see if it works or not.. and perhaps you need to use a commit statement.. which would mean you would need to used OleDbTransaction.Commit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With OleDb and Access, the parameter names are ignored.  You must supply the parameter values in the order in which the db engine expects them.  In your query, Access expects the value for *@nightID* before the value for *@pID*.

So swap those parameters lines like this ...

```
cmd.CommandText = sql;
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nightID", NightID);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pID", PlayerID);
cmd.Connection = conn;
```

Comment: very informative!! thank you - works like a charm :)